# Understanding \is a unit in ssreflect

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I'm really annoyed by the following goal:

```
a%:R \is a unit
```

where `a` is a nat. The only lemma that seems to help is `unitrE`, but then it seems impossible to simplify further. This goal should be solvable. Can someone explain how to coerce this to a field type so I can use `unitfE` which I can easily work with.

Answer (score 1):

you can only use `unitfE` if the structure you work with is a field. Otherwise you need to deal with the characteristic (`[char R]`) of your ring.
What is your structure?

Comment: I think `a%:R` has `numDomainType`. However, it should be a rational number, so I confused as to why I can't use unitfE. The rational numbers are a field.

Comment: so you should have a ```numFieldType```

Comment: I believe that type it is looking for is `(UnitRing.sort unitRingType)`.

Comment: I can `apply/unitrP` which will give me the definition of `\is a unit`, but then the goal is `exists y0 : t, y0 * D%:R = 1 /\ D%:R * y0 = 1` and using `exists D%:R^-1` will place me in the same trap as before.

Comment: `int` and `rat` are two `numDomainType`, so what you would like ```a%:R \is a unit``` to be turned into?

Comment: Ah I actually figured it out. I was using the ssreflect assert syntax `have -> :` for this goal and it was forcing me to prove this for general ring types I think. Applying the same tactics without `have -> :` allowed me to use `unitfE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that `a` is non-zero (which makes sense, to have an inverse), then you can do this:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect all_algebra.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Open Scope ring_scope.
Import GRing.Theory.

Variable (R : numFieldType).

Variable (a : nat).

Definition a' : R := a%:R.

Hypothesis nea'0 : a' != 0.

Lemma a'unit : a' \is a GRing.unit.
Proof. by rewrite unitfE nea'0. Qed.
```